# Reboot and select proper boot device

Tags: boot

Recently I deleted my windows 7 OS and I decided to install Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on my computer.
Two times i booted my pc and i get the message ''reboot and select proper boot device''.

I put the live CD inside and I reboot but I get the same message.
When I turn it off and leave it for about 40 minutes turned off and I restart it again everything is okay. I can log in to ubuntu perfectly.
Do you know why this might happen?
By the way the reason I rebooted my pc was because I wanted to fix with the live CD some bad sectors that the SMART self test found.

I've got a Toshiba Satellite C-660 D
AMD V140 Processor 
OS type 64 bit
disk 244 GB

Answer (score 1):

It sounds more like a hardware issue, and not the software one. One possibility is that heat is causing something to just slightly disconnect, so check all the cables that connect your harddrive (better still, unplug them and then plug them back in). If that doesn't seem to work, call the tech support, visit the computer repair shop... etc.

Comment: Thanks man, I really appreciate your help! My SMART self test shows that I have 3 bad sectors. 2 Reallocated sector count and 1 Current pending sector count. Is there a possibility that this might have caused the problem???

Comment: Without knowing what sectors are bad it's hard to tell, but actually 3 bad sectors isn't a lot. It is possible that i'm wrong and it's just a fluke of (for example) your bios. What got me thinking of a hardware issue is that there is a difference between a cold reboot with 2 minute wait and 40 minute wait. The only thing that changes between such cases is the temperature of the chips and cables.